# How to display numbers of an estimated amount

Tags: usability, forms, tables, experience

Which is the best way to display numbers of an estimated amount of items. for example, if my algorithm can only display the following answers:
at least 5 / above 5

for 'above' it can be something like this:

Devices: 5+

the 'at least' is the tricky one. any suggestions?

---

it is a list of about 10 items that I need to display their count (ordered one after another. like a table)

item x: 5+

item y: 8+

item z: >5

Comment: What about >=5 or min. 5 (short for minimum 5) for at least?

Comment: Are there only the two possibilities "less than 5" and "5 or more", or are there more ranges? And is there a maximal number of items? Maybe something like "0-4", "5–10", "11–50" etc. would be a solution?

Comment: I'm trying to get my head around this and it seems, for the purposes of notation, that "at least 5" and "above 5" are very similar - both meaning "5 or more" with only the slightest nuance between them - Are you sure these are the only output options you're looking at?

Comment: I am looking for a fast eye scan solution. and I feel like words can make it too complicated. Maybe the option of : ≥ 5 |   > 6 can work

Comment: Still not entirely sure about your use case. But maybe colours would be the way to go: If the amount is "critically low" (whatever that means in your situation) display the number highlighted with a red background, for "low" in yellow and for "enough" in green.

Comment: why don't you use words?

Answer (score 0):

At least 5 means that it can be 5 or more, and you would represent this symbolically as >=5. However it is not really an estimate as much as it is some threshold or baseline for a value.

Above 5 means that it is 6 or more (since being equal to 5 is already covered in the previous instance), and you would represent this symbolically as >= 6.

Visually if you put the symbols in front of the numbers then you'll have to put the emphasis or the highlight on the numbers (e.g. colour or styling). If you display it as text you can put the numbers in front (e.g. 5 or more and 6 or more).

However, I don't think there is a clear sense of the use case or how the values are being displayed, so this is as close and I can get to for an answer.